# IntelliJ Haskell plugin: ghc-modi failed with error

Tags: haskell, intellij-idea, ghc, ghc-mod

I just installed IntelliJ idea and the official Haskell plugin.
IntelliJ couldn't find ghc-modi.exe, so I installed ghc-mod through cabal.

However, after importing my cabal project, I am still receiving the following error:

> ghc-modi failed with error: NG BUG: GMECabalFlags (GMEString "extractField: failed extracting configFlags from input, input contained `configFlags'? False")

How can I solve or get more information on this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an incompatability with cabal 1.22, GHC 7.8 and the currect ghc-modi. You should downgrade to cabal 1.20 or upgrade to GHC 7.10 and it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question has been answered by Atsky on [GitHub](https://github.com/Atsky/haskell-idea-plugin/issues/77#issuecomment-70365638):

> This is internal problem of ghc-mod. It fails to read file `dist/setup-config` for some reason.
>   Try to remove `dist` folder from your project and then run `cabal config`.